# Passive Voice : Does it always have to have verb to be ?

Tags: passive-voice

I found this Headline article below :

> Lingerie Retailer Criticized for Image of Model That Appears to Be
>   Edited

Shouldn't retailer be "Retailer was Criticized" ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't retailer be "Retailer was Criticized" ?
The media avoids using past tense to emphasize that the news was fresh- and not stale.

Comment: Interesting theory. Have you a reference supporting it?

Comment: My experiences as a working journalist.

Comment: Have you an independent reference supporting it? Headlinese is generally acknowledged to be more concise and punchier, such qualities being obvious advantages, but omitted verbs may well be present tense. Of course, the historic present is used in novels to bring history to life. I'm not saying your argument is incorrect here.